# The condition for an open set to satisfy the barrier postulate

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**Barrier Postulate**:
there exist for each $\eta \in \partial \Omega$ a function $Q_{\eta}(x) \in C^0(\bar{\Omega}) \cap \sigma(\Omega),$ for which
$ Q_{\eta}(\eta)=0, Q_{\eta}(x)<0$ for $ x \in \partial \Omega, x \neq \eta. $

$\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open, bounded and connected and $\sigma(\Omega)$ denotes the set of functions subharmonic in $\Omega$.

The problem is:

Show that the open set $\Omega$ satisfies the barrier postulate if for each $\eta \in \partial \Omega$, there exists a ball $B(\xi,\rho)$ such that $\bar{B}(\xi,\rho)$ and $\bar{\Omega}$ have just the point $\eta$ in common.

Here is a hint ask me to use for $-Q_{\eta}(x)$ a fundamental solution with spherical symmetry about the point $\xi$, but I don't understand how to find a suitable linear function that vanishes at certain point and negative on the others.

Is there any idea to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome on MSE,

We need to make a distinction of cases depending on the dimension. For simplification I just consider the case $n\geq 3$. Following your hint we consider

\begin{equation*}
b(x)=|x-\xi|^{2-n}
\end{equation*}
which is the fundamental solution multiplied by a constant (to make life a bit easier).

This function satisfies $b(\eta)=\rho^{2-n}$. Hence, it is natural to subtract the constant $\rho^{2-n}$:
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{b}(x)=|x-\xi|^{2-n}-\rho^{2-n}
\end{equation*}

Now all that needs to be done is to check that the other conditions on the barrier are satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I finally figure it out.